# Converting a list to pandas dataframe where list contains dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary

I wanted to convert a `list` to `pandas` dataframe, where the first element of the `list` is a `dictionary`.

I have below code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame([{'aa' : 10}, np.nan])
```

However this fails with below message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 782, in __init__
    arrays, columns, index = nested_data_to_arrays(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 498, in nested_data_to_arrays
    arrays, columns = to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 832, in to_arrays
    arr, columns = _list_of_dict_to_arrays(data, columns)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 912, in _list_of_dict_to_arrays
    pre_cols = lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen(gen, sort=sort)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 374, in pandas._libs.lib.fast_unique_multiple_list_gen
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 910, in <genexpr>
    gen = (list(x.keys()) for x in data)
                ^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Could you please help how to resolve this issue?

Comment: what do you expect from this?

Comment: a dataframe with one column, where first element of that column is `{'aa' : 10}`

Comment: `pd.Series(my_list).to_frame(name='some_name')`.

Comment: @QuangHoang correct. Could you please answer this? I can then accept and close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your list into `np.array`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array([{'aa' : 10}, np.nan]))
```

---

```
            0
0  {'aa': 10}
1         NaN
```

---

Though you list is quite small, here's timings comparison just for the case:

```
In [777]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(np.array([{'aa' : 10}, np.nan]))
26.6 µs ± 220 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

In [778]: %timeit pd.Series([{'aa' : 10}, np.nan]).to_frame()
49.6 µs ± 911 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems more like a bug to me or maybe this behaviour is just intended. The [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor considers your data (*a list with mixed elements*) as a list of dicts while it is not. And the way that I understand it, that's due to [*this*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v2.1.0/pandas/core/internals/construction.py#L532) function that checks only the first item of the list you're passing :

```
def treat_as_nested(data) -> bool:
    """
    Check if we should use nested_data_to_arrays.
    """
    return (
        len(data) > 0
        and is_list_like(data[0])
        and getattr(data[0], "ndim", 1) == 1
        and not (isinstance(data, ExtensionArray) and data.ndim == 2)
    )
```

Interestingly, if we change the order of the elements, the code runs without any problem.

```
print(pd.DataFrame([np.nan, {'aa': 10}]))

            0
0         NaN
1  {'aa': 10}
```

Comment: Very good finding